# dataweave filter, map, order on payload and sting parse to Date

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I tried to implement API in mule

From below CSV data I am looking to implement

```
Region,Country,ItemType,SalesChannel,OrderPriority,OrderDate,OrderID,ShipDate,UnitsSold,UnitPrice,UnitCost,TotalRevenue,TotalCost,TotalProfit
Central America and the Caribbean,Antigua and Barbuda ,Baby Food,Online,M,12/20/2013,957081544,1/11/2014,552,255.28,159.42,140914.56,87999.84,52914.72
Central America and the Caribbean,Panama,Snacks,Offline,C,7/5/2010,301644504,7/26/2010,2167,152.58,97.44,330640.86,211152.48,119488.38
Europe,Czech Republic,Beverages,Offline,C,9/12/2011,478051030,9/29/2011,4778,47.45,31.79,226716.10,151892.62,74823.48
Asia,North Korea,Cereal,Offline,L,5/13/2010,892599952,6/15/2010,9016,205.70,117.11,1854591.20,1055863.76,798727.44
Asia,Sri Lanka,Snacks,Offline,C,7/20/2015,571902596,7/27/2015,7542,152.58,97.44,1150758.36,734892.48,415865.88
Middle East and North Africa,Morocco,Personal Care,Offline,L,11/8/2010,412882792,11/22/2010,48,81.73,56.67,3923.04,2720.16,1202.88
Australia and Oceania,Federated States of Micronesia,Clothes,Offline,H,3/28/2011,932776868,5/10/2011,8258,109.28,35.84,902434.24,295966.72,606467.52
Europe,Bosnia and Herzegovina,Clothes,Online,M,10/14/2013,919133651,11/4/2013,927,109.28,35.84,101302.56,33223.68,68078.88
Middle East and North Africa,Afghanistan,Clothes,Offline,M,8/27/2016,579814469,10/5/2016,8841,109.28,35.84,966144.48,316861.44,649283.04
Sub-Saharan Africa,Ethiopia,Baby Food,Online,M,4/13/2015,192993152,5/7/2015,9817,255.28,159.42,2506083.76,1565026.14,941057.62
Middle East and North Africa,Turkey,Office Supplies,Offline,C,9/25/2013,557156026,10/15/2013,3704,651.21,524.96,2412081.84,1944451.84,467630.00
Middle East and North Africa,Oman,Cosmetics,Online,M,5/12/2013,741101920,5/17/2013,7382,437.20,263.33,3227410.40,1943902.06,1283508.34
Asia,Malaysia,Cereal,Offline,L,7/31/2016,333942162,8/25/2016,9762,205.70,117.11,2008043.40,1143227.82,864815.58
Central America and the Caribbean,Saint Lucia,Cosmetics,Offline,H,7/6/2015,795100581,7/16/2015,6786,437.20,263.33,2966839.20,1786957.38,1179881.82
Central America and the Caribbean,Saint Vincent and the Grenadines,Baby Food,Online,L,11/28/2010,504313504,12/3/2010,6428,255.28,159.42,1640939.84,1024751.76,616188.08
Middle East and North Africa,Lebanon,Meat,Offline,H,12/17/2015,611629760,1/31/2016,3693,421.89,364.69,1558039.77,1346800.17,211239.60
Europe,Austria,Cereal,Offline,C,8/13/2014,987410676,9/6/2014,5616,205.70,117.11,1155211.20,657689.76,497521.44
Europe,Bulgaria,Office Supplies,Online,L,10/31/2010,672330081,11/29/2010,6266,651.21,524.96,4080481.86,3289399.36,791082.50
North America,Mexico,Beverages,Online,C,3/13/2017,127374303,3/20/2017,1742,47.45,31.79,82657.90,55378.18,27279.72
```

a.  List of Orders in a given day. Endpoint should accept Order Date as a required parameter and Country as an optional parameter. If no Country parameter is informed, retrieve all order for the informed date. All order fields should be returned
For the task a, I am not able to parse string to date

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
payload filter (($.orderDate as Date) == attributes.queryparam.orderdate) map ((item, index) -> {
        region: item.Region,
        country: item.Country,
        itemType: item.ItemType,
        salesChannel: item.SalesChannel,
        orderPriority: item.OrderPriority,
        orderDate: item.OrderDate,
        orderID: item.OrderID,
        shipDate: item.ShipDate,
        unitsSold: item.UnitsSold,
        unitPrice: item.UnitPrice,
        unitCost: item.UnitCost,
        totalRevenue: item.TotalRevenue,
        totalCost: item.TotalCost,
        totalProfit: item.TotalProfit

})
```

b.  Sales Report. Endpoint should accept Sales Channel as parameter. It should return Total Number of Orders, Country, Order Priority, and Total Revenue. The data should be grouped by Country and Order Priority and only rows that match Sales Channel parameter

In task b, I want to apply filter,map,groupBy
I tried below code but it’s not working

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
payload filter ($.SalesChannel == attributes.queryparam.salesChannel) map (item, index) -> {
        totalNumberofOrders: 100, 
        country: item.Country,
        orderPriority: item.OrderPriority,
        totalRevenue: item.TotalRevenue

} groupBy $.Country
```

Could you help me with what I did wrong?
Screen shot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTuYI.png)
Thank you

Comment: Please only ask about one issue per question. Open a new question for b)

Answer (score 1):

`$.orderDate as Date` is missing to set the pattern of the date so they can be parsed correctly. DataWeave will not try to guess the pattern. You need to supply one if it not the default. Also the field in the payload is called `OrderDate` so the expression was returning null.

For example for a date like `6/15/2010` which is in format month/day/year and with some dates having a single digit the pattern should be:

```
$.OrderDate as Date {format: "M/d/yyyy"}
```

Comment: can i apply filter, map, orderBy same time like below

%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
payload filter ($.SalesChannel == attributes.queryparam.salesChannel) map (item, index) -> {
        totalNumberofOrders: 100, 
        country: item.Country,
        orderPriority: item.OrderPriority,
        totalRevenue: item.TotalRevenue

} groupBy $.Country

but this code not working

Comment: To be able to help you, please open a new question for that issue. According to Stackoverflow policy a question can be closed if it includes multiple questions in one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Was the answer useful to solve the first issue? Please accept/upvote and remember to create a new question for the second issue.

Comment: Not really, i cannot extract year after 
my task is compare the order date with query param and return that year order objects

my code available in git location : https://github.com/saandeepani/Mulesoft

filter by date code
```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
payload filter (($.orderDate.year as Date {format: "M/dd/yyyy"}) == vars.orderYear)
```

Comment: That is a different issue than the one asked in the question. Feel free to post a new question if you need help. I was asking about the issue in this question.